# In NumPy, how to use a float that is larger than float64's max value?

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.7, numpy-ndarray

I have a calculation that may result in very, very large numbers, that won fit into a `float64`. I thought about using `np.longdouble` but that may not be large enough either.

I'm not so interested in precision (just 8 digits would do for me). It's the decimal part that won't fit. And I need to have an array of those.

Is there a way to represent / hold an unlimited size number, say, only limited by the available memory? Or if not, what is the absolute max value I can place in an numpy array?

Comment: from numpy doc: _NumPy does not provide a dtype with more precision than C’s long double; in particular, the 128-bit IEEE quad precision data type (FORTRAN’s REAL*16) is not available.

For efficient memory alignment, np.longdouble is usually stored padded with zero bits, either to 96 or 128 bits. Which is more efficient depends on hardware and development environment; typically on 32-bit systems they are padded to 96 bits, while on 64-bit systems they are typically padded to 128 bits. np.longdouble is padded to the system default; np.float96 and np.float128 are provided for users who_ ...

Comment: ... _want specific padding. In spite of the names, np.float96 and np.float128 provide only as much precision as np.longdouble, that is, 80 bits on most x86 machines and 64 bits in standard Windows builds.

Be warned that even if np.longdouble offers more precision than python float, it is easy to lose that extra precision, since python often forces values to pass through float. For example, the % formatting operator requires its arguments to be converted to standard python types,_ ...

Comment: Aren't the digits automatically rounded internally? And you only need 8 digits of precision? If so, wouldn't a float64, providing roughly 15 digits of precision, be enough? I'm not too familiar with this topic, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Tyson yes, the decimal part was the issue for me. But using log will solve it. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Ehsan yeah, I saw that. But was looking for a workaround. I'll use log as per suggestion below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you rework the calculation so it works with the logarithms of the numbers instead?

That's pretty much how the built-in floats work in any case...

You would only convert the number back to linear for display, at which point you'd separate the integer and fractional parts; the fractional part gets exponentiated as normal to give the 8 digits of precision, and the integer part goes into the "×10ⁿ" or "×eⁿ" or "×2ⁿ" part of the output (depending on what base logarithm you use).